# Чем заменить UnityEngine.UI и UnityEngine.EventSystems в Unity 2019.3.2f1?

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Собаку уже съел переходя на более новую версию Unity ... Постоянно ругается на класс UnityEngine.UI,UnityEngine.EventSystems и связанные с ним классы. Пробовал удалять в собраном проекте паку Library , заменять ее из старого проекта [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
До устанавливал пакеты . Выбирал сборку :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все равно ошибки связанные с этой библиотекой :

```
Assets\TerrainTools\StampToolExtended\Progress.cs(3,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Assets\SampleScenes\Scripts\ParticleSceneControls.cs(31,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'EventSystem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это исправить нельзя в последней версии Unity2019.3.2f1 . Чем заменить можно UnityEngine.UI, UnityEngine.EventSystems?

Comment: Пробовали reimport all assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки в ваших скриптах из-за того, что они не могут найти нужные namespace - возможно, namespace всех этих классов был просто изменён в новой версии Unity, либо есть ещё другой вариант - т.к. код UI системы был вынесен в отдельный докачиваемый пакет, то на момент запуска редактора у него ещё нет скомпилированного .csprjct. Закомментируйте все места внутри вашего кода, где сейчас происходят эти ошибки. Дайте скомпилировать основной проект, после этого произойдет компиляция проектов пакетов. По-идее, это должно исправить проблему.

Comment: Я начал комментировать , но оказывается  ещё и скомпелированые  библиотеки ссылаются на этот класс UnityEngine.UI

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, А если создать новый проект на этой версии, закинуть манифст с пакетами, дать всему скомпилироваться, закрыть, а затем перекинуть туда папку ассетов из старого проекта?

Comment: решилась проблема ,просто тупым открытием проекта 2018 версии Unity в Unity 2019.... я по привычке удалял папки которые Unity автоматически генерирует в проект , когда открывал его в новой версии Unity